# Linux Mint 18.1 no sound output

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, audio

I can't get the audio working. It's a fresh installation on old Asus eee pc 1001px

```
    kt@minny ~ $ lspci | grep Audio
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High       Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)


kt@minny ~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    16384  3
ccm                    20480  3
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                    98304  2 hid_generic,usbhid
drbg                   28672  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
xts                    16384  1
gf128mul               16384  1 xts
dm_crypt               24576  1
uvcvideo               77824  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    73728  1
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              155648  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec         118784  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           61440  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
arc4                   16384  2
asus_wmi               24576  1 eeepc_wmi
ath9k                 135168  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
snd_pcm                94208  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
ath9k_hw              458752  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
ath                    24576  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
mac80211              659456  1 ath9k
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_seq_midi
coretemp               16384  0
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq                57344  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              499712  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lpc_ich                20480  0
snd                    69632  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 32768  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
mac_hid                16384  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                1003520  0
xor                    28672  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
i915                 1130496  4
ahci                   36864  2
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
psmouse               118784  0
drm_kms_helper        139264  1 i915
libahci                32768  1 ahci
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
atl1c                  40960  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   311296  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
wmi                    20480  1 asus_wmi
fjes                   28672  0
video                  36864  2 i915,asus_wmi
```

**EDIT1:**

```
lspci -k -s 0:1b.0 00:1b.0
```

output:

```
Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

and

```
uname -r
```

output:

```
4.4.0-53-generic
```

Comment: kt@minny ~ $ lspci -k -s 0:1b.0
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
kt@minny ~ $ uname -r
4.4.0-53-generic Thanks @Vlastimil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find solution for you, but for some reason it is not as easy, please try the following.

Edit the following file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Find the line starting with:

> ```
> options snd-hda-intel
> ```

If such line is missing, add it.

Edit this line to contain model number of your laptop:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=*******
```

Where `*******` replace with one of these:

```
eeepc-ep20
```

or

```
eeepc-p701
```

or

```
auto
```

So that the line looks like e.g.:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Reboot.

Comment: It's working correctly, thanks @vlastimil

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to your problem as of 05/07/2017 having experienced the same problem.
Create a live boot of the Linux mint version that you are currently running.

Test your sound card: Menu>> Preferences>> Sound and test the sound.
If there is sound output during the test, switch back to the Installed OS and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded Mint to 19.3 (tricia), GNOME 3.28.2 (Ubuntu), kernal 5.3.0-51-generic and the sound card was not recognised (got Dummy Sound in "Sound" app). You could try this which worked for me. This may be similar to LinuxSecurityFreak's answer, but not entirely sure on that so here it is anyway.

Open up `alsa-base.conf` in the terminal,

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add this to the end,

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

Now save and reboot.